# How can I send a notification from State machine to SNS topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a step function and I want to send a notification to SNS topic once the State Machine completes the execution. I know state machine can trigger Lambda and I can implement the logic in lambda but wanted to checkout if State Machine can directly notify SNS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State Machine does support SNS. You can have a lambda and notify your SNS from there but you can directly use SNS with SFN without using any Lambda. Below you can see the implementation:

```
{
  "Publish to SNS to notify DataDog": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
    "Parameters": {
      "TopicArn": "<SNS topic ARN>",
      "Message.$": "$",
      "MessageAttributes": {
        "notify": {
          "DataType": "String",
          "StringValue": "Send to SNS"
        }
      }
    },
    "Next": "<Next state>"
  }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-sns.html)